# What is SerializeFromObject in spark execution plan?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I read [here](https://medium.com/teads-engineering/lessons-learned-while-optimizing-spark-aggregation-jobs-f93107f7867f) that `SerializeFromObject` is performed when we go from DataSet to DataFrame. Is there official documentation that describes this in more detail?

Does this mean that going from DataSet to DataFrame is a relatively expensive operation, since it performs serialization?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about *official* documentation, but for Spark as open-source project, its source code would be the *ultimate* doc. And, according to [SerializeFromObjectExec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/objects.scala#L134) operator's source, it indeed does map an RDD of Java objects to an RDD of `InternalRow`s using serializer  (kryo-, java-, or other/custom).

```
/**
 * Takes the input object from child and turns in into unsafe row using the given serializer
 * expression.  The output of its child must be a single-field row containing the input object.
 */
case class SerializeFromObjectExec(
:
  override protected def doExecute(): RDD[InternalRow] = {
    child.execute().mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal { (index, iter) =>
      val projection = UnsafeProjection.create(serializer)
      projection.initialize(index)
      iter.map(projection)
    }
  }  
:
```

As we see here, the `doExecute` goes and applies UnsafeProjection (which "wraps" a serializer) on each partition to produce an RDD of InternalRows. In the query plan, we would also find a `MapPartitions` node added prior to SerializeFromObject.